# Can Highcharts sort a legend list in a tooltip box?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to display statistical data.

As you see the below figure, is it possible to reorder a list of legend?

[image]

I tried to sort the graph itself, but it looks like really tricky because of its data structure.

In other words, this approach is workaround to display data in order.

Comment: What order do you want the data? Can you show us your chart code please.

Comment: My data comes from an internal data service. That's why I don't write my code here because it won't work. Anyway, thanks Steve for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great example that sorts the tooltip based on y value: [want to sort highcharts tooltip results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867607/want-to-sort-highcharts-tooltip-results)

If you want to sort them by the country names you can give each series a name or id and then sort your chart based on given name or id in tooltip formatter

you can give id, name when adding series like:

```
   chart.addSeries({
                name: your name,
                data: your data,
                id: your id,
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

List of series in tooltip is the same as series order. In case when you would like to prepare your own tooltip content, you can use formatter: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! Bon journée!